# plm::pdata.frame loses variable label attributes created by labelled::var_label?

Tags: r, attributes, plm, modelsummary, r-labelled

I have a panel data to which I have applied `plm::pdata.frame` to be able to use the `lag` operator. However, once I have converted by dataframe to pdata.frame, the variable labels that I created using `labelled::var_label` do not show up in `modelsummary::msummary()`, rather the variable names show up. Is there anything I can do to make sure that variable labels, not names show up in `msummary()`?

Answer (score 1):

Those "labels" are actually `attributes` that apparently get lost during conversion. You can try to reassign them to your pdata.frame. *Example:*

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))  ## toy df
dat[] <- Map(`attr<-`, dat, 'foo', 1:4)  ## assign some labels named 'foo'

str(dat)  ## check structure
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ X1: int  1 2 3
# ..- attr(*, "foo")= int 1
# $ X2: int  4 5 6
# ..- attr(*, "foo")= int 2
# $ X3: int  7 8 9
# ..- attr(*, "foo")= int 3


pdat <- plm::pdata.frame(dat)  ## convert to pdata.frame
str(pdat)  ## check for attributes
# Classes ‘pdata.frame’ and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ X1: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
# ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "1-4" "2-5" "3-6"
# ..- attr(*, "index")=Classes ‘pindex’ and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
# .. ..$ X1: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
# .. ..$ X2: Factor w/ 3 levels "4","5","6": 1 2 3
# $ X2: Factor w/ 3 levels "4","5","6": 1 2 3
# ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "1-4" "2-5" "3-6"
# ..- attr(*, "index")=Classes ‘pindex’ and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
# .. ..$ X1: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
# .. ..$ X2: Factor w/ 3 levels "4","5","6": 1 2 3
# ...
```

Now we can see, that there are new attributes, but the old are lost. However we can reassign them easily using `` `attributes<-`() ``:

```
pdat[] <- Map(`attributes<-`, dat, lapply(dat, attributes))
str(pdat)
# Classes ‘pdata.frame’ and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
#   $ X1: 'pseries' Named int  1 2 3
# ..- attr(*, "foo")= int 1
# ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "1-4" "2-5" "3-6"
# ..- attr(*, "index")=Classes ‘pindex’ and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
# .. ..$ X1: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
# .. ..$ X2: Factor w/ 3 levels "4","5","6": 1 2 3
# $ X2: 'pseries' Named int  4 5 6
# ..- attr(*, "foo")= int 2
# ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "1-4" "2-5" "3-6"
# ..- attr(*, "index")=Classes ‘pindex’ and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
# .. ..$ X1: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
# .. ..$ X2: Factor w/ 3 levels "4","5","6": 1 2 3
# ...
```

`` `attributes<-`() `` will assign all attributes of `dat` to `pdat`. To only select specific labels, use `` `attr<-`() `` with the label name.

Notice that your attributes probably called `"labeled"` not `"foo"`, I don't use `labelled`. See if this works and your labels show up in the summary.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to give such a detailed answer. I've tried following your suggestion. It seems that even after I re-assigned the attributes using your suggested method, ```modelsummary::msummary()``` doesn't show the variable labels, but rather shows the variable names.

Comment: `?modelsummary::msummary` says it takes model objects as input. Maybe try to apply the trick to the model frame inside the model object, i.e., to `<your_plm_model_object>$model`.

Comment: @Helix123 Please use `@` to notify OP, thanks.